# What is the default root password for a Toshiba Chromebook 1?

Tags: chrome-book, toshiba

I powerwashed my device, so that it would be 'brand new,' but now I don't have sudo access. I am using a Toshiba Chromebook 1, which is a linux device. What is the default root password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to access `sudo` without a password when no password is set.

As stated from the linked source:

> By default, you can login as the chronos user with no password.  This includes the ability to do password-less sudo.

To access the virtual terminal press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>=></kbd>. Where <kbd>=></kbd> is the right arrow key just above the number <kbd>3</kbd> on your keyboard (it should be <kbd>F2</kbd>).

[source](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/poking-around-your-chrome-os-device#TOC-Get-the-command-prompt-through-VT-2)